# Uninstalled POW server but now cannot reach external .dev sites

Tags: dns, rack-pow

I tried the Anvil server accessory for Mac OSX, which installed Pow.  I decided after trying it I didn't have any real use for it, so ran the uninstall.

Except now I can no longer reach any of my company's .dev sites! At the DNS level, I would guess POW is still hijacking the .dev calls, and of course failing.

I need all traces of this software off my system, so I can reach all our .dev sites and develop as usual.  As it stands, I am now dead in the water.

I am on 10.8.2. I tried rebooting as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug in the uninstaller as of this writing.  It left a router file at `/etc/resolvers/dev`.  I renamed this file to `dev1` and rebooted, problem gone.